# Flutter PDF generated document margins

Tags: flutter

I am creating my first PDF document in Flutter using the pdf package.

Here you have a partial screenshot from the pdf part that I need to change:

[image]

You may see 6 rows, each of them has a time and a string.

Here you have the code for that screenshot:

```
  static Widget buildTablaDiario(List<dynamic> listaDiarioActual){

    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: listaDiarioActual.length,

        itemBuilder: (pw.Context context, index){

          DiarioModelo diario = listaDiarioActual[index];

          DateTime tempDateI =
          new DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
              .parse(diario.fecha_diario);

          String date1 = DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm")
              .format(tempDateI);
          String hora = DateFormat("HH:mm")
              .format(tempDateI);
          return Row(
            children: [
              pw.Text("${hora}"),
              pw.SizedBox(width: 10),
              pw.Text(diario.descripcion,overflow: TextOverflow.clip)
            ]

          );

        }

    );
 }
```

I would like to set a right margin in order to avoid the text lines to end at the right edge from the document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know it's late, but in case anyone is still looking for an answer...
inside pw.Page or pw.MultiPage there is a margin attribute where you can add paddings

```
pdf.addPage(
    pw.MultiPage(

      pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,

      **margin: const pw.EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),**

      orientation: pw.PageOrientation.portrait,...
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is the following:
Before pdf.save() run the following to add your custom margins

```
  for (int i = 1; i < pdf.document.pdfPageList.pages.length; i++) {
      pdf.document.pdfPageList.pages
          .elementAt(i)
          .pageFormat
          .copyWith(marginLeft: 50, marginTop: 100, marginRight: 50, marginBottom: 50);
    }
```